Azure Pipelines breaking suddenly with no RUN button to Manually trigger
We noticing a few issues in Azure pipelines like:-

Suddenly Azure pipelines don't have RUN button enabled to trigger them manually
Some failing with Error:- Length cannot be less than zero. Parameter name: length
Lot of pipelines getting triggered on its own

IS there Any maintenance work going on without prior notification anywhere?
I am trying to trigger existing working pipelines manually, expected behaviour is to have RUN button to trigger it.

Looks like global ADO issue https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Error-when-running-a-pipeline:-Length-ca/10659456?fTime=6m&sort=newest

As mentioned by @Marcin, there is a public incident: https://status.dev.azure.com/_event/503803593
Some users should start seeing improvements in executing existing pipelines and creating new pipelines. You can monitor on the link above and try again after it's fully mitigated.
Edit: The incident has been fixed, please check again.

Thanks for the update! Glad to know it's resolved! Happy day!
